# How do I define multiple equations in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to define two formulas in excel, and then make a 2 variable data table to run these formulas through.

My formulas are:

```
Q = SQRT( 2*U*A ) / SQRT(h)
```

and if you use that best quantity Q then the acquisition and holding costs yield a corresponding

```
TOTAL COST = SQRT( 2*U*A ) * SQRT(h).
```

The table uses the last equation, however I am so confused on how to define these equations.

Comment: Do you want to know how to write these as expression in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you determine which equation to use based on an if then condition (assumption because you said "if you use best quantity Q), you could write;

=if (test condition, equation if true, equation if false)

Where test condition is an operation with a true false or 1 or 0 output.